# Cannot align to right or left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have this LaTeX code which should place this two images on the left and the right of the page:

```
\begin{flushright} \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=107px ,
height=134px]{t1.jpg} \end{figure}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft} \begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=113px ,
height=190px]{t2.jpg} \end{figure}
\end{flushleft}
```

but the two images are placed one at the top of the other, why??

Comment: `flushright` and `flushleft` are not standard latex environments. Are you loading some package or special documentclass that is providing them?

Comment: @Lev: No, you are wrong. Both of these environments are provided by LaTeX. They are the environment versions of `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`.

Comment: @Martin. You appear to be right. Not sure why I thought otherwise.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

`figure` is a floating environment. It is not placed directly but stored and placed where LaTeX thinks it fits best. This can be influenced by the optional argument like `[H]` but surrounding alignment environment still don't have any influence on it.

`flushleft` and `flushright` produce paragraphs and therefore a line break. So both contents will always vertical stacked, never side by side.

Note that you don't need a `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`, only if you want a caption. Also you can have multiple images and captions (!) in one `figure`. Try the following code to place the two images side-by-side and at the left and right corner (if this is what you want):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=107px,height=134px]{t1.jpg}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=113px,height=190px]{t2.jpg}%
\end{figure}
```

Comment: your code place them side by side but on the same level , why?

Comment: @smack: The images are aligned at their baseline which is at the bottom. If you want to have them also vertical aligned you can put the `\includegraphics` commands also in a `\raisebox{-.5\height}{...}` command each.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any `figure` environment, if you don't want to add a caption. Just write

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=107px,height=134px]{t1.jpg}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=113px,height=190px]{t2.jpg}
\end{center}
```

The two images will be vertically aligned at their bottom.

Comment: Egreg: Would it be optimal to use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in this case of two figures with no captions, rather than using `\centering`?

Comment: `center` will add some vertical space fore and aft; `\centering` requires braces *and* a final `\par` before the closing brace.

Answer (score 2):

Some more explanations:

First of all, a `figure` environment is actually a `\vbox` of width `\columnwidth` (with many properties). It is impossible to put two successive `figure` environments (float or non-float) side by side.

Furthermore, you cannot use `flushleft` environment and `flushright` environment to typeset side by side materials. The two environments are defined using `trivlist` environment. They can only placed vertically, if not included in other boxes.

You should, as Martin does, put the two images into one `figure` environment. And use `subcaption` or `subfig` package if you want separate sub-captions.

Answer (score 0):

If the figures are related, you could also create one figure with subfigures.

There is a package available to do this: subfig

For subfig,

```
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[]}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[]}
...
\end{figure}
```

There are more details on options in their respective package descriptions.
Also mentioned in the comment is subcaption

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore. As Leo Liu suggested, `subfig` or, even better, `subcaption` can be used instead.

Comment: thanks... i wasnt sure about that... i'll update the answer